# Why are my sessions randomly not saving?

Tags: php, session, session-cookies

We fixed an issue we had with a browser from not being able to log in on subdomains by adding the following line of code.

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.'.get_domain('http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']));
```

The get_domain function gets the domain of a site so that "sub.sub.domain.com" will return "domain.com". We prepend a "." so that our sessions are good across all subdomains.

That fixed the issue of not being able to login but the problem now is that ever since we added this line of code we will ***randomly*** not be able to login because the sessions aren't created and are just NULL.

I say randomly because I can't figure out what's causing it. One day a user is able to login, they try to login the next day and it doesn't work. Clearing the cookies will usually solve the issue. Any idea what I might be doing wrong? I've tried googling but haven't found anything that has helped, our users are getting frustrated and I'm running out of ideas. Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had forgotten to change this setting in one of the headings which was throwing everything out of whack.

(Sorry for answering my own question, up voted everyone for the help)

Answer (score 1):

> Clearing the cookies will usually solve the issue.

Looks like there is a caching problem to me but this is only an assumption.

From your description alone it's hard to tell whether the problem lies on the browser-side or the server-side.

The best suggestion I can give to you is to implement a cookie test on the login form. Before the user actually enters his/her credentials your're setting a test-cookie and redirect to the same page with an additional `test` get-parameter. If the page is requested with this additional `test` parameter it's checked if the test cookie was successfully set.

Only allow to login if the test passed. Otherwise give an error message and inform the user about the technical problem.

This might help you to identify when the problem actually occurs. Additionally you can even add more information from the server-side in case of an error that might help you to debug the problem.

Comment: I'm using session cookies and not setting cookies manually through the set_cookie function. Are you saying I should see if creating a cookie is possible before logging on? I don't really understand your GET test suggestion.

Comment: The test is just to test if setting a cookie works and only offer a login form if setting a cookie has worked. To test if a cookie could be set you need to set the cookie, make the browser do an additional request and within that additional request check if the cookie was set. The test cookie is another cookie then the session cookie. Are you setting many more other cookies?

Comment: Thanks, but turns out I had forgotten to make the change in one of my headers. I'm embarrassed.

Answer (score 1):

Just to rule it out please try setting the domain with a constant string rather than deriving it with `get_domain()` something like this:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.foo.com');
```

Have a good look in your browser for cookies both set on `.foo.com` and any old ones that might be set (or being set) on `sub.foo.com`

I've seen some problems similar to the one that you've described due to some cookies not being visible to different servers. The problem is along the lines that `sub.foo.com` might have a cookie entry already defined that you didn't remove and only it will be able to see it. A new cookie is set from `www.foo.com` on `.foo.com` as `www.foo.com` is unable to see the `sub.foo.com` cookie.

I hope that made sense...

Comment: So you think www.foo.com might not see the cookies of sub.foo.com? I'm trying to figure out exactly what I'm looking for before hardcoding the value because we currently have ~45 websites running off this login script all with a different domain name. Hardcoding this value could lock everyone out (which means I'd probably have to do it during off hours :))

Comment: Hmmm turns out I had forgotten to make the change in one of my headers (*facepalm*) which was causing problems depending on where you were coming from.